# overload moose object with sub moose object to be just regular datatype structure

Tags: perl, operator-overloading, moose

I'm trying to get a moose object, which has moose objects to be referenced as just a nested set of plain perl datatypes, that I can refer to as a hashref. e.g.

```
my $ref = { %{ $obj } }
```

and the structure might be like

```
{
  name => "bob",
  phones => [
    {
      phone_number => "15555554698"
    },
  ]
}
```

instead of

```
bless( {
  name => "bob",
  phones => [
    bless( {
      phone_number => "15555554698"
    }, 'PhoneNumber' )
  ]
}, 'User' )
```

here's my attempt

```
use overload '%{}' => '_hashref';

sub _hashref {
    my $self = shift;

    foreach my $attr ( $self->meta->get_all_attributes ) {
        if ( $attr->has_read_method ) {
            say $attr->name;
            say $attr->get_value( $self );

        }
    }
    return {};
}
```

unfortunately `get_value` seems to do something recursive, and runs until it segfaults. I tried passing it `__PACKAGE__` and just `'User'` but neither seem to work. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might get the attributes and the values so that I can operate on them? or another smarter way to do this? *note: I'm aware that I'm currently returning an empty hashref, at this point just trying to figure out how I might get at the values*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "recursive" thing that `get_value` is doing is trying to access
`$self->{$slot_name}`, which is calling your `%{}` overload, which is calling `get_value`... You can work around this by temporarily defeating the overloading (there's an [example in the overload docs](https://metacpan.org/module/overload#Two-face-References)), or you could stop trying to reimplement what [MooseX::Storage](https://metacpan.org/module/MooseX%3a%3aStorage) already does pretty well.